# Bosun External TSDB API

Tags: bosun

Just starting to play with bosun.

Currently, we push all our TSDB data to an external PAAS (https://www.runabove.com/iot-paas-timeseries.xml)

Is there any way to use bosun with the data store in an external PAAS (API-compliant) ? (look like the logstash configuration)

Edit 1 : The PAAS is compatible with OpenTSDB (i.e. I can add it easily to grafana as data source, I would like to do the same for Bosun)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Bosun will only work with an OpenTSDB, InfluxDB, or Graphite backend. You can use a cloud hosted version of one of those, and there is at least one user running OpenTSDB on top of [Amazon's Elastic MapReduce](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) which is a managed hadoop cluster. You may however still need to tune the cluster to work with OpenTSDB.

Comment: The PAAS is compliant with OpenTSBS (for example, I can it easily to grafana as a data source). I'm looking for a way to do this in Bosun